# app.get() no longer respond after adding Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

This is app.js, localhost:3000 shows

> haha, invalid page

Then added a new sub folder `angular-src` and had all angular cli stuffs there. I also ran `npm install` and `ng build` there.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
var path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

global.__rootdir = __dirname;
app.get('/', (req, res) =>
{
    res.send("haha, invalid page");
})

/* After adding this block, local:3000 won't show haha, it shows content of app.component
const myNgController = require("./controller/myNgController");
app.use('/myNg', myNgController);
*/

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => 
{
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: haha... But you don't add appropriate route, as specified in the code comment.

Comment: @TGrif please explain more

Comment: According to the comment, you have to set up a controller to serve your angular app, and a route to point to it.

Comment: @TGrif if you meant `require("./controller/myNgController")`, yes I have that, `ng build` didn't  see problem. `app.use('/myNg', myNgController);` so it only applies on path `/myNg`, not on the root.

Comment: `ng build` is not related with server side.

Comment: @TGrif You're right. The controller dictates `/myNg` path, how would it both the root GET?